# ASP.NET MVC Code Coverage Coloring

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, tfs, code-coverage

I want to confirm one thing,Please check the below image of some piece of code first :-

[image]

I am doing the Unit Testing in my MVC application.And i am checking the code coverage of my controller by TFS.But while i enable the "show code coverage coloring" option from "Code Coverage Results" it enables the coloring option.

But i am not sure whether the colored code is "Covered" or un colored code is "Covered" ?

Can anyone let me know that ?

Answer (score 0):

Lines highlighted light blue were exercised in the test run. Lines highlighted beige were partially exercised. Lines highlighted reddish-brown were not exercised at all